# I lost my app source files, but have the app on my iPad

Tags: xcode

I've been working on an app for a while on a school computer, and had it nearly finished before the computers were wiped without my knowledge and with no warning.

I have the nearly finished app, however, published to my iPad under my own Developer App profile. Would there be any way for me to get the app from my iPad and unpack it somehow? I've looked the question up already and some have said that you can unpack it with some third party software, but it doesn't say what the software actually is.

I would really appreciate some help with this. I have a version of the app backed up, but it's much older and I would rather not redo things if I didn't have to.

Comment: What language did you write it in?

Comment: It's written in swift.

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer is no.

Swift (and objective C) is compiled into machine code and much of the naming is thrown away and optimisation will also alter the control structure.

Experienced reverse engineers can get some form of code back but it is not very readable or useful in most cases.

When you start any coding project the first thing you do is set up source code control so you can take snapshots of code.

Note that the " wiped without my knowledge and with no warning" should be expected on any computer. Hardware can fail let alone errors an people mistakenly or deliberately removing files.